# Bibliography - English in reverse in a Hebrew article

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, hebrew, english

I'm new with LyX, and now learn.

I wrote something in Hebrew, and add bibliography (in English) and its in reverse:
[image]

The code:

```
בדיקה\cite{Ruan2003}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

The bib file:

```
@Article{Ruan2003,
language={english},
hyphenation={english},
  author        = {Ruan, YiJun and Wei, Chia Lin and Ling, Ai Ee and Vega, Vinsensius B and Thoreau, Herve and Thoe, Su Yun Se and Chia, Jer-Ming and Ng, Patrick and Chiu, Kuo Ping and Lim, Landri and others},
  title         = {Comparative full-length genome sequence analysis of 14 SARS coronavirus isolates and common mutations associated with putative origins of infection},
  journal       = {The Lancet},
  year          = {2003},
  volume        = {361},
  number        = {9371},
  pages         = {1779--1785},
  __markedentry = {[MyLaptop:6]},
  publisher     = {Elsevier},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

Any idea?

The complete code (MWE):

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
   \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
 \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
בדיקה \cite{Ruan2003}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{db}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it's me from the second question (I haven't logged in).   The code I showed are compiled.

Comment: Hey, Thank you. I'm sorry for that all. Here is the full code (I hope.. )
https://pastebin.com/ni4bNE9n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I do not have installed your hebrew code I can not compile with your hebrew text but I can show you the correct bibliography.

You need to tell LaTeX to use english language and writing for the bibliography with

```
\selectlanguage{english} % <============================================
```

The complete MWE (together with your bib file)

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
   \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
 \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}


\begin{document}
בדיקה \cite{Ruan2003}

\selectlanguage{english} % <============================================
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{db} % 

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: eenglish bibliography]

Comment: it's working! Thank you!